# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: message is not defined Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm in the process of creating a Discord bot that will read from a specific Google Sheets spreadsheet and this error keeps coming up as I am trying to integrate the Google Sheets functions. [See Github Repo](https://github.com/nafoster/tokunetbot) and please know I'm extremely new at Node.js.

For this function, I have created **index.js** to get everything running for both discord.js and the Google API:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require("fs");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const readline = require('readline');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2Client = google.auth.OAuth2;
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';
 
/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
const authorize = function (credentials, callback) {
    const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
 
    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
}
 
/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
const getNewToken = function (oAuth2Client, callback) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES,
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
        rl.close();
        oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
            // Store the token to disk for later program executions
            fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                if (err) console.error(err);
                console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
            });
            callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
    });
}



//pulls all commands and events
fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    const eventHandler = require(`./events/${file}`);
    const eventName = file.split(".")[0];
    client.on(eventName, (...args) => eventHandler(client, ...args));
  });
});

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
 
module.exports = {
    authorize,
    google
}
```

**Sheets.js** contains the readAll function for Sheets I want to use so when someone types in assignments!all the function should run:

```js
const {authorize, google} = require('./index');
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require('readline');
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const spreadsheetId = "1asvhCVI1sC6Q2cCuqdUrRqFHkH2VCr5FM7kWSm8VBE8";

//read entire spreadsheet
const readAll = (range) => {
    fs.readFile('client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
        if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
        // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
        authorize(JSON.parse(content), (auth) => {
            const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
            sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
                spreadsheetId, range
            }, (err, res) => {
                if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error:' + err);
                const rows = res.data.values;
                if (rows.length) {
                  // Print columns B through F.
                  rows.map((row) => {
                    message.reply(`Details: ${row[0]}, Link: ${row[1]}, Additional Link: ${row[2]}, Assigned To: ${row[3]}, Assigned On: ${row[4]}, Ready for QC on: ${row[5]}, QC Link: ${row[6]}`);
                  });
                } else {
                  console.log('No data found.');
                }

            });
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    readAll
};
```

As I plan to have the bot do more functions in the future, I have created a **message.js** file in an events folder to call commands from a commands folder:

```js
const assignments = require('../commands/assignments');
const assign = require('../commands/assign');
const qc = require('../commands/qc');
const qcList = require('../commands/qcList');
const sheets = require('../sheets');

module.exports = (client, message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('assignments!')) {
        return assignments(message);
    } else if (message.content.startsWith('assign!')) {
        return assign(message);
    } else if (message.content.startsWith('qc!')) {
        return qc(message);
    } else if (message.content.startsWith('qclist!')) {
        return qcList(message);
    }
};
```

**Assignments.js** actually tells the bot that when the word "all" is used after the ! in "assignments!", that is when it is suppose to run the ReadAll function on the specific tab in the Sheets spreadsheet:

```js
// gets all assignments or assignments based on name given after !
module.exports = (message, google, authorize, readAll) => {
    
    const sheets = require('../sheets');
    
    //ex message: assignments!Brody
    //gets name after ! and stores as member variable
    var messageContent = message.content;
    var member = messageContent.split('!')[1];   
    var member = member.toLowerCase();
    
    //test reading spreadsheet
    if(member === 'all') {
            sheets.readAll("Active News Assignments!B2:F");
    }
   
        
    //error messages
    if (!member) {
        message.reply("You must add a name or 'all' after the command.");
    }
};
```

Again, I am very new to Node.js and following these tutorials to create this bot. Please feel free point out anything obvious I'm missing or ways I can simplify my code once it's working as I know I will be adding more functions in the future.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/making-a-custom-discord-bot-in-discord-js-1e17f2090919
https://www.ishaanrawat.com/integrate-google-sheets-api-with-node-js/

Comment: What are the file names & which ones are the events? (Considering you are assigning events to their name). You also don't seem to have the `message` parameter on the `readAll` function.

Comment: @Steamgamer I've bolded the file names in my question. The event is in message.js and the command is assignments.js.

Comment: Right, but the issue still stands that the `readAll` function does not have a message parameter, so it will produce an error when doing `message.reply()`.

Comment: @Steamgamer Thank you for clarifying. I've added it as part of `const readAll = (range, message)` in sheets.js but it looks a new error message came out `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'reply' of undefined` Perhaps I'm not sure where the message function should be in readAll.

Comment: You need to now pass the message object so it can use the method `send()`.